# Unable to resolve some project in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

i'm working on asp.net core project in visual studio 2017
everything is good but sometimes i getting this error:

```
Unable to resolve 'D:\Path\Module.Cataloge.Domain\Module.Cataloge.Domain.csproj' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'
```

csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Platform.Core\Platform.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

so, how to solve this error? and what's the error said?

Comment: Can you please share .csproj content?

Comment: @Sanket sorry, i forgot it, but there's nothing special. i edited my question.

Comment: It's very likely that there's something specific to your context which we don't know about. Try to create a [mcve] from the ground up, that might help you find the root cause and otherwise will provide us with more info on how to repro and help.